# PHP exif_read_data return only specific tags

Tags: php, exif

Is there a way for exif_read_data to return only specified values?

When I run this on my images I get all kinds of info returned , even some UndefinedTag with breaks my json. Since I only need some tags like FileName, DateTime, Make, Model how could I request only those tags?

```
$exif = exif_read_data('IMG_20210302_065231.jpg');
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
       echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way to solve using the foreach loop outlined would be to have the keys of the array desired and use `in_array` to perform the check. If the key is in the `$allowedKeys` array then it will be included.

The other approach would be to just json_encode all the output so you aren't losing data from the exif function.

```
<?php

$exif = exif_read_data('IMG_1591.jpeg');

// Approach 1 (key found)
$allowedKeys = ['FileName','FileDateTime'];
$values = [];
foreach($exif as $key => $val) {
  if(in_array($key, $allowedKeys)) {
     $values[] = [$key => $val];
  }
}
var_dump(json_encode($values));
// Output: string(58) "[{"FileName":"IMG_1591.jpeg"},{"FileDateTime":1615402941}]"

// Approach 2 (straight output to JSON)
var_dump(json_encode($exif));
// Output: string(274) "{"FileName":"IMG_1591.jpeg","FileDateTime":1615402941,"FileSize":192200,"FileType":2,"MimeType":"image\/jpeg","SectionsFound":"ANY_TAG, IFD0","COMPUTED":{"html":"width=\"1119\" height=\"839\"","Height":839,"Width":1119,"IsColor":1,"ByteOrderMotorola":0},"Software":"Google"}"
```